# a chickgoer, who cannot help but think of girls around

Tags: idioms, culture, idioms-in-context

So lets say Ive got a friend who goes after pretty girls and only thinks about girls, trying to lure her out whenever he sees one.
I want to call him a *chick-goer*(or chickgoer) for him. I know there is no such definiton in dictionary, I literally rigged it up or maybe Ive seen it but I find it reasonable and viable. Anyways, if I use it, people will clearly get what I said?

Answer (score 2):

English is pretty flexible when it comes to the creation of compound words. However, your suggestion doesn't make sense and wouldn't be understood to mean what you hope it would.

The suffix '-goer' means that someone goes *to*, or *attends* something. For example, *churchgoers* are people who go to church, and *moviegoers* ('*cinemagoers*' in the UK) are people who go to the movies. So, a 'chickgoer', if there was such a thing, would mean someone who goes *to* a chick, and that doesn't mean anything. There are probably already a lot of existing words to describe your friend - he sounds like a *[womanizer](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/womanizer)*, or maybe he's just a *[horndog](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/horndog)*.

Comment: An older word that would be similar in derivation (girl+seek) would be "skirtchaser"

Comment: @Kevin I've not heard that one. But my first suggestion links to a thesaurus for more options.